# Validate data before serializing it to JSON

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm developing an app where a user is entering data. This data is serialized to JSON. If a user enters "" or multiple lines, the app crashes. I need any kind of JSON validator that will get rid of these characters before serializing the data.

Comment: And have you tried `try{}catch(){}`

Comment: I want to use regex

Comment: How r u serializng the data  ?

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

Comment: Are you sure you're not having any [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Is it possible to validate the user-input instead of the JSON?